# Anyone know of a good .Net Chess Engine

Tags: .net, chess

I'm looking for a decent .Net chess engine.  If there is a good chess existing one, any recommendation as to a good candidate to port to .Net?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not an engine as such, but [Valil.Chess](http://www.valil.com/winfx/) is a good .NET chess game (with source code available - so you can get to the "engine" of the game) which won the [Nov 2004 Submission Prize](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/01/24/517109.aspx) at Code Project.

There is also [SharpChess](https://github.com/PeterHughes/SharpChess), which is also a complete chess game, written in C#.

As for general Chess engines that could be converted to .NET, there are many available, and depending upon the challenge, you could pick and choose from lots of engines to implement within .NET.  A good starting point list is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_engine#Freely_available_chess_engines) and also shows the [Elo Rating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) of each engine.  Even a re-implementing of the server-side of the [FICS](http://www.freechess.org/) would certainly represent a challenge!  :)

Answer (score 9):

I write a Computer Chess Blog that takes you through all the steps of writing a chess engine in C# from scratch, it includes a computer chess links section and a chess game starter kit.

http://www.chessbin.com

Adam Berent

Comment: Hi! is the blog post still available? the link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The SharpChess Engine code (C#) is available here:

[Search Engine Source Code](http://sharpchess.com/?page=50%20Development/02%20Engine%20Code)

Comment: The best open source C# chess engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SharpChess](http://sharpchess.com/) or [ChEngine](http://www.codeplex.com/ChEngine/).

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend [SharpChess](http://sharpchess.com/) as a starting point for .Net.  When I developed my engines (in VB, Delphi, C#) I constantly referred to [Crafty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crafty) by Prof Dr Robert Hyatt.  (Looking at progressive versions of Crafty is a delight.)

Answer (score 0):

For those arriving here many years later, I checked the most popular suggestion among the other answers - which apparently is **SharpChess** - and it seems quite **outdated** at this moment; last commit was 6 years ago, there are many pending issues, broken links and the unit tests seems incomplete and not enough to demonstrate how the engine works, at least to most people that are unfamilar with chess engines.

I found this project called [StockChess](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1159746/StockChess) that is a simple WPF application making use of a executable of a chess engine called [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/about/), claiming to be `the strongest open source chess engine nowadays`.

I found that **StockChess** has a reasonable explanation of how it works on its [page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1159746/StockChess). You can probably use it as a starting point and that's what I'm doing.